# Selecting XML column without column alias wrapping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query that returns the following XML result set.
Notice the nested `<Configuration>` elements in the **Query 1 Results**.

**Question:**

If I add a case statement, it removes the column name from the xml output. Which gives me the expected result.  How can I do this without the case statement, or a nested select?
*See Query 2 & Query 2 Results for an example.*

**Query 1:**

```
   SELECT
        (SELECT
             q.NotificationQueueId
            ,nc.Configuration -- Provides unexpected result -- Nested <Configuration><Configuration /></Configuration>
            ,q.UserAdded
            ,q.DateAdded
            ,q.UserEdited
            ,q.DateEdited
            ,q.IsActive
        FROM Queue q
            INNER JOIN NotificationConfigurations nc ON nc.NotificationConfigurationId = q.NotificationConfigurationId
        FOR XML RAW ('NotificationItem'),TYPE)
    FOR XML RAW ('NotificationItems'),TYPE
```

**Query 1 Results:**

```
<NotificationItems>
  <NotificationItem NotificationQueueId="1" UserAdded="someone" DateAdded="2016-02-29T13:26:11.110" IsActive="1">
    <Configuration>
      <Configuration>
        <Email AddressList="blah@blah.com" Subject="blah blah blah">       
        </Email>
      </Configuration>
    </Configuration>
  </NotificationItem>
</NotificationItems>
```

**Query 2:**

```
   SELECT
        (SELECT
             q.NotificationQueueId
            ,CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN nc.Configuration END -- Provides expected result
            ,(SELECT nc.Configuration) -- Provides expected result
            ,q.UserAdded
            ,q.DateAdded
            ,q.UserEdited
            ,q.DateEdited
            ,q.IsActive
        FROM Queue q
            INNER JOIN NotificationConfigurations nc ON nc.NotificationConfigurationId = q.NotificationConfigurationId
        FOR XML RAW ('NotificationItem'),TYPE)
    FOR XML RAW ('NotificationItems'),TYPE
```

**Query 2 Results**

```
<NotificationItems>
  <NotificationItem NotificationQueueId="1" UserAdded="someone" DateAdded="2016-02-29T13:26:11.110" IsActive="1">
    <Configuration>
      <Email AddressList="blah@blah.com" Subject="blah blah blah">       
      </Email>
    </Configuration>
  </NotificationItem>
</NotificationItems>
```

**Table definitions:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NotificationConfigurations](
    [NotificationConfigurationId] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [Configuration] [xml] NOT NULL,
 )

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Queue](
    [NotificationQueueId] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [NotificationConfigurationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserAdded] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [DateAdded] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UserEdited] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [DateEdited] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
)
```

**Example Configuration Xml:**

```
<Configuration>
    <Email AddressList="blah@blah.com"
           Subject="blah blah blah">
    </Email>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: I'm suspecting you've got some unusual input data. Could you add some (basic) table definitions and some sample data that produces these results please?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: updated with table schema and example configuration.

Comment: What is the raw value of `nc.Configuration` for this example?

Comment: @TT.: See the section labeled: Example Configuration Xml.

Comment: I'll try and build a sqlfiddle -- the site is having issues at the moment, though.

Comment: orite =) missed that with all the samples ;). Looks like expected behaviour then. The inline select drops the column name, hence no extra surrounding element. Same for the CASE statement

Comment: You can also select the column as `[text()]=nc.Configuration`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the example:

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 1 AS ID UNION SELECT 2
), t2 AS (
SELECT 1 AS ID, CONVERT(XML, '
    <Configuration>
        <Email AddressList="blah@blah.com" Subject="blah blah blah">       
        </Email>
    </Configuration>
    ') As Configuration
)
SELECT (
    SELECT t1.ID,
        t2.Configuration,
        CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN t2.Configuration END,
        (SELECT nc.Configuration)
    FROM t1
    INNER JOIN t2 On t1.ID = t2.ID
    FOR XML RAW ('NotificationItem'),TYPE
) FOR XML RAW ('NotificationItems'),TYPE
```

Your `Configuration` field is already XML with `<Configuration />` root tag. When selected it is being wrapped in an extra `<Configuration />` tag following the field name.

You already have the solution through `(SELECT nc.Configuration)` which results in "anonymous" field that is included into result XML "as is", without field name wrapping tag. And this "nested query" does not actually cost anything.

**Update**: Of cause `Configuration` XML can be explicitly "unwrapped" before `JOIN`, but that would be much less efficient:

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 1 AS ID UNION SELECT 2
), t2 AS (
SELECT 1 AS ID, CONVERT(XML, '
    <Configuration>
        <Email AddressList="blah@blah.com" Subject="blah blah blah">       
        </Email>
    </Configuration>
    ') As Configuration
)
SELECT (
    SELECT t1.ID,
        t2sub.Configuration
    FROM t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ID, sub.ConfigurationContents.query('.') AS Configuration
        FROM t2
        CROSS APPLY Configuration.nodes('/Configuration/child::node()') AS sub(ConfigurationContents) 
    ) t2sub ON t2sub.id = t1.id
    FOR XML RAW ('NotificationItem'),TYPE
) FOR XML RAW ('NotificationItems'),TYPE
```